# ArrayFormula and Categorize Data in Google Sheets using Regular Expressions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I'm following this [post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97405/how-to-categorize-data-in-google-spreadsheet-using-regular-expressions) to categorize data in Google Sheets using regular expressions.

The person who wrote the answer was able to get the formula to automatically write down the category in column D.

I assume they used ArrayFormula to achieve it, but I can't seem to get it done. Or they just paste the formula to each cell of the column. I'm not sure.

The formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:B,MATCH(TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(C2,INDIRECT("A"&2&":A"&3+COUNTA(B$2:B)))),0),2))
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18tjkqpQET4oQ8yuZ0hI7nB60pTrFw_7ycPfX69qsY3o/edit?usp=sharing) is the sample Sheet I made as an example.

What I am looking for is to categorize data in column C based on the keywords in column A.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks so much.

[image]

Comment: for a faster and more complete answer, it would be convenient to have the link to your file and also know what result you would like to obtain

Comment: @Daniele Thanks for your answer. I just updated the question. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18tjkqpQET4oQ8yuZ0hI7nB60pTrFw_7ycPfX69qsY3o/edit?usp=sharing) is the sample sheet I made. Thanks!

Comment: that formula is set to be dragged, note that a range of type C2:C has NOT been provided in this part: `REGEXMATCH(C2...`

Comment: @Daniele I tried that. But it doesn't seem to work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SnVA.png

Comment: yes, it doen't work because that formula didn't foresee it... I'm searching for an alternative

Comment: the doubleunary genius found you the alternative I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

To find the category in column `B` where the regex in column `A` matches the phrase in column `C`, use `filter()`, like this:

`=+filter( B$2:B, regexmatch(C2, A$2:A) )`

Put the formula in cell `D2` and copy it down.

To do the same automatically down the column, use `vlookup()` with wildcards:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      "*" & regexextract(C2:C, "(?i)" & textjoin("|", true, A2:A)) & "*", 
      A2:B, columns(A2:B), false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

To find the word in column `C` that matches the regex in column `A` per the category given in column `D`, use `vlookup()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( regexextract( C2:C, "(?i)" & vlookup(D2:D, { B2:B, A2:A }, 2, false) ) ) )`

Put the formula in cell `E2`.

Comment: There is something I do not understand ... the column to be filled and which is therefore initially empty is precisely column D, so why do you use it in the formula you gave? (if column D was empty, your formula would give an empty result)

Comment: Edited the answer. It was unclear which columns in your sample spreadsheet are sample data and which show the desired results. The answer now assumes that you simply want to array enable the formula you already have in cell `D2`.

Comment: "To do the same automatically down the column..." I'm sorry, I think there is an error ... in this formula too you refer to column D, creating a circular dependency

Comment: Thanks Daniele, edited the answer.

Comment: a beautiful piece of code !